# Django - model instance being saved (or not)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two Django models, `ModelA` and `ModelB`. The latter has a foreign key link to the former.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    item = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In the production code, an instance of `ModelA` is saved. During the same function, it seems to automatically save an instance of `ModelB`, as this is accessed in the template.

```
def view(request):

    a = ModelA()
    a.item = True
    a.save()

    b = ModelB.objects.filter(modela_id=a.id)

    return render(request, 'template.html', context=locals())
```

Firstly, although this is how I want the code to work, I am not sure how the instance of `ModelB` is saved. (This is inherited code - I can't find a signal or call to ModelB anywhere else in the codebase).

Secondly, this behaviour has stopped working in local development (but still works in production, with identical code); `ModelB` is not saved, so `b` returns `None`. I am pretty sure it's not a code issue as old branches of the code have the same problem. I have tried restoring my local db to a previous version, to no avail. The only thing that changed recently is that I squashed a load of migration files.

Can anyone help with these questions? I'm running Django 1.11.

Comment: If you can't find the code that saves the ModelB instance, what makes you think we would be able to with limited access to the code?

Comment: With your code, ModelB should never exist & your filter query should be empty. You create and save ModelA and only search for ModelB with a filter criterion that searches for ModelB instances that link to ModelA. This may only work if you have a post_save handler on ModelA that creates and saves a ModelB instance linking to ModelA. 

As to why this works in production: Are you sure that the production code that you see is still the same than the one that ran when the system got deployed? Without a restart, you might see newer *.py files than the ones that are used by the production server...

Comment: Yep, sorry - this was posted in desperation. You're completely right @ingofreyer - I found the issue was there are triggers for this behaviour in the MySQL database - the triggers had been missed out of the copy to local databases. Absolutely nothing in the code to say this was happening though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comment was correct, here is the answer to the question:

With the code you gave us, ModelB should never exist and your filter query should be empty. You create and save ModelA and only search for ModelB with a filter criterion that searches for ModelB instances that link to ModelA.

This may only work if you have a post_save handler on ModelA that creates and saves a ModelB instance linking to ModelA.

As to why this works in production: This could happen by new code replacing the current *.py files but no server restart happening yet. As the author of the question found out, there was a MySQL trigger in place creating ModelB instances. This trigger was not available in the development system.